# How to find number in a cell

Tags: arrays, if-statement, instr

Could you please help me to solve this issue with a vba code?

this is my data

[image: data]

What I want to do is to create a vba code that search the value from column B in Column C

if the value is found or not found then in column A add a comment

the issue is when in Column C,  I have an array, I mean:

Side B

(2,5) = 2,3,4,5
(1,8) = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
.
.
.

this is my code, but it does not work:

[image: error]

I would really appreciate your help.